# Tukey Post Hoc Anova shows unexpected degrees of freedom

Tags: r, anova, emmeans, posthoc, tukey

I am running an anova in R using lme4 package to investigate the effects of LUT and Climate on EMF (dataset with 50 observations below). Afterwards, to investigate, where the effect occurs, I perform a tukey posthoc analysis using lsmeans package. Surprisingly, the degrees of freedom for the different comparisons are not always 32 (as expected), see screenshot attached. Anyone sees the solution to that?

[Results pairwise comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLBap.png)

```
contrast        estimate     SE   df t.ratio p.value
 CF amb - EM amb  0.03087 0.0401 32.0   0.770  0.9986
 CF amb - EP amb  0.00557 0.0428 33.2   0.130  1.0000
 CF amb - IM amb -0.04434 0.0401 32.0  -1.107  0.9804
 CF amb - OF amb -0.17754 0.0385 32.6  -4.610  0.0021
 CF amb - CF fut  0.03547 0.0409 39.7   0.867  0.9967
 CF amb - EM fut  0.09094 0.0409 39.7   2.222  0.4595
 CF amb - EP fut  0.07230 0.0409 39.7   1.767  0.7511
 CF amb - IM fut  0.02319 0.0409 39.7   0.567  0.9999
 CF amb - OF fut -0.09254 0.0409 39.7  -2.261  0.4350
 EM amb - EP amb -0.02530 0.0428 33.2  -0.591  0.9998
 EM amb - IM amb -0.07520 0.0401 32.0  -1.877  0.6833
 EM amb - OF amb -0.20841 0.0385 32.6  -5.411  0.0002
 EM amb - CF fut  0.00460 0.0409 39.7   0.112  1.0000
 EM amb - EM fut  0.06008 0.0409 39.7   1.468  0.8966
 EM amb - EP fut  0.04143 0.0409 39.7   1.012  0.9897
 EM amb - IM fut -0.00768 0.0409 39.7  -0.188  1.0000
 EM amb - OF fut -0.12341 0.0409 39.7  -3.015  0.1089
 EP amb - IM amb -0.04990 0.0428 33.2  -1.166  0.9727
 EP amb - OF amb -0.18311 0.0418 35.4  -4.379  0.0035
 EP amb - CF fut  0.02990 0.0436 39.8   0.685  0.9995
 EP amb - EM fut  0.08538 0.0436 39.8   1.957  0.6321
 EP amb - EP fut  0.06673 0.0436 39.8   1.530  0.8720
 EP amb - IM fut  0.01762 0.0436 39.8   0.404  1.0000
 EP amb - OF fut -0.09811 0.0436 39.8  -2.249  0.4426
 IM amb - OF amb -0.13321 0.0385 32.6  -3.458  0.0426
 IM amb - CF fut  0.07980 0.0409 39.7   1.950  0.6368
 IM amb - EM fut  0.13528 0.0409 39.7   3.305  0.0557
 IM amb - EP fut  0.11664 0.0409 39.7   2.850  0.1549
 IM amb - IM fut  0.06753 0.0409 39.7   1.650  0.8155
 IM amb - OF fut -0.04821 0.0409 39.7  -1.178  0.9716
 OF amb - CF fut  0.21301 0.0394 39.0   5.404  0.0001
 OF amb - EM fut  0.26849 0.0394 39.0   6.812  <.0001
 OF amb - EP fut  0.24984 0.0394 39.0   6.339  <.0001
 OF amb - IM fut  0.20073 0.0394 39.0   5.093  0.0004
 OF amb - OF fut  0.08500 0.0394 39.0   2.156  0.5017
 CF fut - EM fut  0.05548 0.0401 32.0   1.385  0.9232
 CF fut - EP fut  0.03683 0.0401 32.0   0.919  0.9946
 CF fut - IM fut -0.01228 0.0401 32.0  -0.306  1.0000
 CF fut - OF fut -0.12801 0.0401 32.0  -3.195  0.0788
 EM fut - EP fut -0.01864 0.0401 32.0  -0.465  1.0000
 EM fut - IM fut -0.06775 0.0401 32.0  -1.691  0.7922
 EM fut - OF fut -0.18349 0.0401 32.0  -4.580  0.0024
 EP fut - IM fut -0.04911 0.0401 32.0  -1.226  0.9624
 EP fut - OF fut -0.16485 0.0401 32.0  -4.115  0.0083
 IM fut - OF fut -0.11574 0.0401 32.0  -2.889  0.1505

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 10 estimates
```

```r
# create dataset
# Create dataframe
emf_data <- data.frame(
  Block = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10),
  Plot = c("01_1", "01_2", "01_3", "01_4", "01_5", "02_1", "02_2", "02_3", "02_4", "02_5", "03_1", "03_2", "03_3", "03_4", "03_5", "04_1", "04_2", "04_3", "04_4", "04_5", "05_1", "05_2", "05_3", "05_4", "05_5", "06_1", "06_2", "06_3", "06_4", "06_5", "07_1", "07_2", "07_3", "07_4", "07_5", "08_1", "08_2", "08_3", "08_4", "08_5", "09_1", "09_2", "09_3", "09_4", "09_5", "10_1", "10_2", "10_3", "10_4", "10_5"),
  LUT = c("EM", "CF", "EP", "OF", "IM", "IM", "EP", "OF", "CF", "EM", "CF", "OF", "IM", "EM", "EP", "CF", "OF", "IM", "EM", "EP", "OF", "IM", "EM", "CF", "OF", "EP", "CF", "EM", "OF", "IM", "OF", "EM", "EP", "IM", "CF", "IM", "EP", "EM", "CF", "OF", "EM", "IM", "CF", "EP", "OF", "EP", "EM", "OF", "IM", "CF"),
  Climate = c("amb", "amb", "amb", "amb", "amb", "fut", "fut", "fut", "fut", "fut", "amb", "amb", "amb", "amb", "amb", "fut", "fut", "fut", "fut", "fut", "amb", "amb", "amb", "amb", "amb", "fut", "fut", "fut", "fut", "fut", "fut", "fut", "fut", "fut", "fut", "amb", "amb", "amb", "amb", "amb", "fut", "fut", "fut", "fut", "fut", "amb", "amb", "amb", "amb", "amb"),
  EMF = c(0.386534098, 0.46301213, 0.490665819, 0.721414456, 0.509056576, 0.464901551, 0.428232861, 0.52899388, 0.399248469, 0.36825831, 0.449465674, 0.614773512, 0.489035327, 0.386153492, 0.484446186, 0.541415126, 0.631957258, 0.444547778, 0.375668212, 0.407520486, 0.716481701, 0.536012334, 0.541456363, 0.453584094, 0.393995629, 0.430187565, 0.382135054, 0.384626746, 0.59484382, 0.402980148, 0.516302924, 0.344090374, 0.344659404, 0.455428398, 0.413082427, 0.447645874, 0.412076009, 0.373668918, 0.449430167, 0.703724138, 0.33978796, 0.383338418, 0.353935011, 0.295040775, 0.457778567, 0.404055142, 0.424999363, 0.635655693, 0.507076667, 0.451659421)
)

## install.packages("lme4")
## install.packages("lsmeans")
library(lme4)
library(lsmeans)
model <- lmer(EMF ~ LUT * Climate + (1 | Block), data = emf_data)
emm <- lsmeans(model, ~ LUT * Climate)
pairwise_comp <- pairs(emm, adjust = "tukey")
summary(pairwise_comp)
```

Link to the dataset:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zr1Bh7_RxUyYftmKCNiv36rIs92eIGce/view?usp=sharing

Comment: By default, the `lmer` function uses the Satterthwaite approximation to estimate the degrees of freedom for the fixed effects. If you specifically want to obtain integer degrees of freedom, you can use the `lmerTest` package. `install.packages("lmerTest")`

Comment: @Phoenix, almost but not quite. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One of the [emmeans vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/sophisticated.html) (`emmeans` is the newer version of `lsmeans`, and you're encouraged to switch ...) explains that the Kenward-Roger estimate of the denominator degrees of freedom (ddf) is used (this is also stated at the bottom of the printout of your pairwise contrasts):

> You will notice that the degrees of freedom are fractional: that is due to the fact that whole-plot and subplot variations are combined when standard errors are estimated. Different degrees-of-freedom methods are available. By default, the Kenward-Roger method is used, and that’s why you see a message about the `pbkrtest` package being loaded, as it implements that method. We may specify a different degrees-of-freedom method via the optional argument lmer.df: `emmeans(Oats.lmer, "nitro", lmer.df = "satterthwaite")`

(However, the Satterthwaite approximation will *also* give you fractional df estimates that vary among contrasts (because different groups have different variances.)

There are other, more traditional methods of estimating ddf ("containment", "between-within"), e.g. as used in `nlme::lme()`. They do always give integer estimates, and estimates that are identical across groups, but they aren't available in `emmeans` (they're less popular nowadays because they don't generalize well to unbalanced designs and complex [e.g., crossed] random effect structures).

My advice is not to worry about it too much; for example, the difference between 32 and 39 df in a t-distribution, for a t-statistic of 2.5, is the difference between `2*pt(-2.5, 32) == 0.0177` and `2*pt(-2.5, 39) == 0.0167` ...